# Why did Rust go with "match" instead of "switch" or "case"?

Tags: rust

I'm curious about the history of this. I would assume `switch` would appeal to C/C++/Java/etc programmers and thus be a natural choice. If one wanted to avoid confusion in semantics (since `match` is more powerful than `switch`) I'd assume one would borrow `case` from Haskell instead.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[The Rust Reference cites](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/influences.html) Standard ML (SML) and OCaml as an influence for pattern matching. In OCaml, [pattern matching uses the `match` keyword](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora016.html).

[The original Rust compiler was written in OCaml](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6932601), so it makes sense that OCaml would have had a stronger influence on Rust than, say, Haskell.